# String assignment with spaces returning null

Tags: java, string, null, variable-assignment

How come when i put //private String namespace = "###Name:"+name+"                ###"; and system.out.println(namespace) it comes out null?

I am suppose to create a tagmaker program, but I am stuck at how to line up the # on the right side.

```
/*################################################
###               ANNUAL CONFERENCE            ###
############################################### #
###Name:Simon                             ###
###                                           ###
############################################### #
###Organization:NBA             ###
###                                             ###
################################################*/
```

How do I line them up for any given name that I set it to?
I am suppose to Set the Name, Set the organization, Print tag with the name and organization, Clear the name and organization, and Print a blank tag.

----------------UPDATE 4:09AM----------------------------
I am just going to model my code after this:

```
public class Divers {
    public static void main(String args[]){
      String format = "|%1$-10s|%2$-10s|%3$-20s|\n";
      System.out.format(format, "FirstName", "Init.", "LastName");
      System.out.format(format, "Real", "", "Gagnon");
      System.out.format(format, "John", "D", "Doe");

      String ex[] = { "John", "F.", "Kennedy" };

      System.out.format(String.format(format, (Object[])ex));
    }
   }
```

but can someone show me how i can do it the other way? just for learning purposes

```
public class AddressBookTester {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
TagMaker test =  new TagMaker("Simon", "NBA");

test.printlL();

    }

}

public class TagMaker {

private String name;
private String organization;
private String l = "################################################";
private String annual= "###               ANNUAL CONFERENCE            ###";
//private String namespace = "###Name:"+name+"                ###";
private String l2= "###                                             ###";
//private String organizationspace= "###Organization:"+organization+"###";
TagMaker (){

}

TagMaker (String tempName, String tempOrg){
name = tempName;
organization = tempOrg;

}
    void setname(String tempName){
        name = tempName;
    }

    String getname(){
        return name;
    }

    void setorganization(String tempOrg)
    {
            organization = tempOrg;
    }

    String getorganization(){
        return organization;
    }


    void printlL(){
        System.out.println(l);
        System.out.println(annual);
        System.out.println(l);
        System.out.println("###Name:"+name+"                             ###");
        System.out.println(l2);
        System.out.println(l);
        System.out.println("###Organization:"+organization+"             ###");
        System.out.println(l2);
        System.out.println(l);

    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using tabs or spaces?

Comment: Hint: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length(%29

Comment: i am working with spaces

Comment: @S.Lott why is it when i put
//private String namespace = "###Name:"+name+"                ###";
and I do system.out.println(namespace); it prints out null?

Comment: @CuriousStudent.  Are you aware that `//private string...` is a comment?  It does nothing.

Comment: @S.Lott I made it a comment because it returned a Null value. Let us say that i removed the// and i did system.out.println(namespace); it prints out null

Comment: @CuriousStudent: It can't.  You're omitting some code.  Open a **separate** question with the real code that really produces the real null -- and **only** that code.  Be sure it compiles and produces the null without clutter from other, unrelated problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a constant for the Maximum width (in characters) of your output. Then you can do some simple arithmetic to work out how many spaces/characters etc. you need to properly format your output.

Say if max_width = 60.

Here's a header:
`############################################################` <sub>(the full 60)</sub>

The you work out the indents and things based on the length in chars of the strings you're outputting.

e.g. If you want to print `Name: Simon` get the length of this and subtract from max_length, etc. etc.

HTH.

Comment: How do I do it the way you described? I think I am just going to revise my code after this

public class Divers {
  public static void main(String args[]){
      String format = "|%1$-10s|%2$-10s|%3$-20s|\n";
      System.out.format(format, "FirstName", "Init.", "LastName");
      System.out.format(format, "Real", "", "Gagnon");
      System.out.format(format, "John", "D", "Doe");

      String ex[] = { "John", "F.", "Kennedy" };

      System.out.format(String.format(format, (Object[])ex));
  }
}

Comment: If you do not mind, can you show me how to do it this way? I am going to revise my code to the .format option, but for learning purposes I would like learn the way you described. thank you

Comment: You're not going to learn much from this lab exercise if someone on StackOverflow writes your code for you ;-)

Think about mine and @DerMike's suggestions and *try* it. You have all the basic information you need.

HINT: do it with low-level constructs like if/else, and for loops to get the maximum benefit from the exercise.

Good luck.

Comment: @5arx I would have to set this as a variable then right? Instead of this  System.out.println("###Name:"+name+"             ###");
I have to write private String namespace = "###Name:"+name+" ###"; and system.out.println(namespace)?

but when i do that it seems to come out null for the name

Comment: Say you have an int 'max_length' set to 60.

1. So you use a for loop to print '#' max_length number of times. This gives you your header, and, at the end, your footer.

2. You have an int to represent the number of chars for your left and right indents - say its 3.

So for each line you output you will have 3 indents + a space + the name or org + a space + 3 more indents. If you subtract this from the max_length you'll get the number of spaces you'll need to right pad your line with BEFORE you output the final space + 3 indents which you need at the end of a line.

That sort of thing.

HTH.

Comment: * Sorry typo: should read: "If you subtract the LENGTH of this from the max_length ..."

Comment: by chars, do you mean charAt or characters in general?

Comment: Great. I hope you enjoyed the exercise. Good luck with the rest of your course :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a good look at String.format(...), particularly the [Formatter documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). It's a bit complex to start with, but it does allow you to print strings with a fixed length (i.e. padded out with spaces).

You might also [find this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0463.html) page helpful, which has a couple of worked examples (although you will have to adapt and modify a fair bit).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find out how long your lines are. Second you determine the length of the text inside the badge. Finally you insert the spaces dynamically to have of lines with equal lengths.

Comment: If you do not mind, can you show me how to do it this way? I am going to revise my code to the .format option, but for learning purposes I would like learn the way you described. thank you